# Solidus API Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, spree, solidus

Right now I'm looking at the edit product view in the admin interface, but every time I try to find the option types, my api returns a 404. This appears to be because Select2 is hitting the following url: `/ecommerce/api/option_types?...` (not including the actual query on purpose), even though my api url should be at `/store/api/` since I have the following in my `routes.rb` file: `mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/store'`

I confirmed that when I switch the code to `mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/ecommerce'` temporarily in my `routes.rb` file, my option types appeared correctly in the select2 select box.

My only guess is that earlier in the project, I had mounted the spree engine at `/ecommerce` (ie `mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/ecommerce'`). But I have since changed the code to mount it at `store`, and after that have restarted the rails server in the terminal and made sure to hard refresh the browser (in case there was a caching issue somewhere), but still the select2 form is hitting the wrong route (`/ecommerce/api/option_types?...`).

I tried digging through the source code, but it gets very dense very quick with select2 and its js and everything, haha.

Any guesses on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I was not able to reproduce the issue. But later I figured it out. The issue is caused by rails caching the assets... you can fix the issue simply by removing the content of `tmp/cache/assets/` directory.

Why is the issue happening? The routes used in the backend for JS API calls are defined and stored in the JS object `Spree.routes`, youn can inspect its contents in the browser javascript console.

These URLs prefix comes from `Spree.pathFor` defined in `core/app/assets/javascripts/spree.js.erb`:

```
Spree.mountedAt = function() {
  return "<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.spree_path(trailing_slash: true) %>";
};
```

While `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.spree_path` changes when you change the Spree mount path, this JS file, once generated, is not going to change, as its MD5 checksum is still the same. So the cached version in the `tmp/cache/assets/` directory is going to be used.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! At first it didn't work because (and this is, of course, my fault) I erased the cache, then tried again without reloading the page first. When I erased the cache and then reloaded the page _before trying to use the form_, it worked great! (Should be obvious to most people but just wanted to jot that down just in case)